# show directly that the eigenfunction of the given Sturm-Liouville problem are orthogonal

Tags: orthogonality, orthonormal, sturm-liouville

show directly That the eigenfunction of the given Sturm-Liouville problem are orthogonal without explicitly solving for therm , and state the orthogonality conditions

${y}''+\lambda (1+x)y=0$

$y(0)=0$

${y}'(1)=0$

I'm solving it this way

$r^{2}+\lambda  (1+x)=0$

$r^{2}=-\lambda  (1+x)$

$r=\sqrt{-\lambda  (1+x)}$

$\lambda  (1+x)=k$

$r=\sqrt{-k}$

$r=\sqrt{k}i$

How do I use the suggestion you give me?. I've to confess that I'm a bit lost, can anyone give me a hint ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a solution $y_1$ with $\lambda=\lambda_1$ and a solution $y_2$ with $\lambda=\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_1-\lambda_2 \ne 0$. Then the eigenfunctions are orthogonal with respect to the weight function $1+x$, but not necessarily with respect to the weight function $1$:
$$
    (\lambda_1-\lambda_2)\int_0^1 y_1(x)y_2(x)(1+x) dx = \\
   =\int_0^1 y_1y_2''-y_1''y_2 dx \\
   = \int_0^1(y_1y_2'-y_1'y_2)'dx \\
   = y_1y_2'-y_1'y_2|_0^1 =0.
$$